# Generating multiple lines output from single line input in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My requirement is to generate multiple lines of output by using single line of input in pig scripting. What are the possible solutions?

Comment: One solution is that I should use UDFs or streaming functionality of PIG to do this.

Answer (score 7):

The idea is to convert you input line into a bag and then flatten it.  Here could be 2 cases:

Reading text:

```
txt = load '/pig_fun/input/text.txt' using TextLoader();
words = foreach txt generate TOKENIZE($0);
pivoted = foreach words generate FLATTEN($0);
dump pivoted;
```

**Input:**

```
My requirement is to generate multiple lines of output by using single line of input in pig scripting.
What are the possible solutions?
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
(My)
(requirement)
(is)
(to)
(generate)
(multiple)
(lines)
(of)
(output)
(by)
(using)
(single)
(line)
(of)
(input)
(in)
(pig)
(scripting.)
(What)
(are)
(the)
(possible)
(solutions?)
```

Reading columns and then pivoting them see [Pivot table with Apache Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213567/pivot-table-with-apache-pig)