# Pivoting in Pig

Tags: pivot, apache-pig

This is related to the question in [Pivot table with Apache Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213567/pivot-table-with-apache-pig).
I have the input data as

```
Id    Name     Value 
1     Column1  Row11 
1     Column2  Row12 
1     Column3  Row13 
2     Column1  Row21 
2     Column2  Row22 
2     Column3  Row23
```

and want to pivot and get the output as

```
Id    Column1 Column2 Column3 
1      Row11    Row12   Row13 
2      Row21    Row22   Row23
```

Pls let me know how to do it in Pig.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do it without UDF is to group on Id and than in nested foreach select rows for each of the column names, then join them in the generate. See script:

```
inpt = load '~/rows_to_cols.txt' as (Id : chararray, Name : chararray, Value: chararray);
grp = group inpt by Id;
maps = foreach grp {
    col1 = filter inpt by Name == 'Column1';
    col2 = filter inpt by Name == 'Column2';
    col3 = filter inpt by Name == 'Column3';
    generate flatten(group) as Id, flatten(col1.Value) as Column1, flatten(col2.Value)  as Column2, flatten(col3.Value)  as Column3;
};
```

Output:

```
(1,Row11,Row12,Row13)
(2,Row21,Row22,Row23)
```

Another option would be to write a UDF which converts a bag{name, value} into a map[], than use get values by using column names as keys (Ex. vals#'Column1').

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about pig, but in spark, you could do this with a one-line command

```
df.groupBy("Id").pivot("Name").agg(first("Value"))
```