# Pig transform triples to columns

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following data structure (stored in triples)

```
id1 type1 data1
id1 type2 data2
id2 type1 data3
id2 type2 data4
```

I'd like to run it thought pig to get a table like this:

```
    type1,type1
id1,data1,data2
id2,data3,data4
```

I can only think of it solving through a number of filters and joins. I'd appreciate if someone can suggest me a more efficient solution.

many thanks.

Comment: You need pivoting, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578815/pivoting-in-pig