# Dynamically generating new schema in Pig

Tags: schema, apache-pig

I want to pivot some data in Pig, using the values in the row I am pivoting on as my column names. I do not know these values in advance. I want these new column names to be stored as the schema of each of the relevant values.

This is the same question as [Pivoting in Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578815/pivoting-in-pig?lq=1), but with dynamically generated column names.

Right now I have a bag of tuples like

```
{(C1, V1), (C2, V2), (C3, V3), ... (Cn, Vn)}
```

and I'd like to change them to something like:

```
dump bag;
{ (V1, V2, V3, ... Vn) }

describe bag;
bag: {C1: chararray,C2: chararray, ... , Cn: chararray}
```

I'm currently trying to do this with a UDF that overrides `outputSchema()`, but I'm having trouble accessing my column names because `outputSchema()`'s input is expected to be a Schema object, and Schema objects do not allow using `input.get(<field-num>)` to access field values. Is there another way to dynamically create a new schema?

The reason I'm so married to using a schema is because I'm eventually exporting to CSV.