# How can I compute the combination of two fields using Pig script?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have input like:

```
(1, (a, b, c))
(2, (e, f, g))
```

The output I expected is like:

```
(1, a)
(1, b)
(1, c)
(2, e)
(2, f)
(2, g)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help you:

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (int:a, t1:tuple(t1a:chararray, t1b:chararray,t1c:chararray));

B = FOREACH A GENERATE a,t1.$0,t1.$1,t1.$2;

C = group B by a;


X = COGROUP C BY a, C BY $0;

DUMP X;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (f1:int,T:tuple(f2:chararray,f3:chararray,f4:chararray));
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,FLATTEN(TOBAG(T.f2,T.f3,T.f4));
DUMP B;
```

Comment: Seems it doesn't work, the output is still: `(f1, T.f2, T.f3, ...)`.

Comment: I found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213567/pivot-table-with-apache-pig). Just need one more `FLATTEN`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Load input file

1   a,b,c

2   e,f,g

as

crude_input = load '' USING PigStorage() AS (id:int, ip_tuple:tuple(val1:chararray, val2:chararray, val3:chararray));

dump crude_input;

(1,(a,b,c))

(2,(e,f,g))

**Step 2**:

crude_flatened = foreach crude_input GENERATE id, FLATTEN($1);

This will generate

(1,a,b,c)

(2,e,f,g)

Step 3:

output_data = foreach crude_flatened generate id, FLATTEN(TOBAG(ip_tuple::val1,ip_tuple::val2,ip_tuple::val3));

(1,a)

(1,b)

(1,c)

(2,e)

(2,f)

(2,g)