# Dummy column in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, unpivot

My current table structure has the following columns:

```
id, name, height, weight
```

I need to un-pivot it so that a single `id` will have 2 entries - one for height and one for weight.  The query would be like this in Hive:

```
select id, name, "height" attribute, height as value
from table1
union all
select id, name, "weight" attribute, height as value
from table1
```

How do I do this in Pig?

Comment: Maharaj : words are not enough.Post some code you tried or your sample data to get better response.

Comment: @Maharaj : Share sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a duplicate, but close to:
[Pivot table with Apache Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213567/pivot-table-with-apache-pig).

Here is a solution.

BTW, I am assuming you had a typo in line 4 of your query.

```
raw = load 'data.txt' as (id, name, height, weight);
a = foreach raw generate id, name, TOBAG(('height', height), ('weight', weight)) as vbag;
b = foreach a {
generate id, name, flatten(vbag);
};
dump b;
```