# Building a dictionary out of a value of a column

Tags: apache-pig

How do you build a dictionary of words/tokens (stored vertically) out a value of a specific column? This column may contain space/tab separated content.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Is the dictionary you want just a list of unique words? Is it supposed to be sorted? Can you give an example input? Is what you're looking for similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205235/generating-multiple-lines-output-from-single-line-input-in-pig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted to do is more or less the same as in this question.

[Generating multiple lines output from single line input in pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205235)